# php mail being seen as spam why when i have headers

Tags: php, email

I dont see why my php headers is being detected as spam please can someone see if anything wrong
     $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

```
  $headers .= "Reply-To: Polar White Kit <info@teethwhiteningsuperstore.com>\r\n"; 
   $headers .= "Return-Path: Polar White Kit <iinfo@teethwhiteningsuperstore.com>\r\n"; 
   $headers .= "From: Polar White Kit <info@teethwhiteningsuperstore.com>\r\n"; 
   $headers .= "Organization:  Polar White Kit\r\n";
```

Comment: Which method do you use for sending mails?

Comment: I believe the best way to prevent the server to recognize the email as spam is sent via SMTP.

Comment: There's more to spam detection than simply checking headers - more information needed about what is filtering your mail as spam, on what rules?

Comment: You need to identify exactly what tests are failing with the spam detection and fix each in turn

Comment: You need to do [a lot more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/396/766580) to avoid your email being detected as spam.

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spam detection is all done by whichever client and server receives the email. It goes through a big set of rules to give the email a spam rating. If the rating goes above a certain level, it's marked as spam.

Some of those rules include the content of the email itself - the words, images, etc. Other rules look at where the email was sent from - SPF records, domain reputation, IP address, etc.

This is a huge topic, much more than I can answer here. Check out:

- http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/
- http://www.lyris.com/resources/email-marketing/contentchecker
- http://www.allspammedup.com/2009/09/7-ways-to-prevent-your-emails-being-blocked-as-spam/