# PHP mailer unable to send html messages

Tags: php, html

I tried sending HTML mails through PHP but nothing is working. I tried two options.

One with `file_get_contents`:

```
<?php
$to = 'teas@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Marriage Proposal';
$from = 'support@blabla.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = file_get_contents("email_template.html");

// Sending email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}
?>
```

And one with HTML in a PHP string:

```
<?php
$to = 'anthony@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Marriage Proposal';
$from = 'peterparker@email.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Jane!</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

// Sending email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}
?>
```

The response for both functions is:

> Unable to send email. Please try again. Unable to send email. Please
>   try again.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Did you set your SMTP server correctly in `php.ini`?

Comment: everything is working fine.i have sent a total of 10k emails till now in plain text.but when i implement HTML it gets error.
if those plain emails are getting delivered then it mean that everything is fine.idk still

Comment: To clarify the title, this is using the mail() function in php, not "PHPMailer".   Big difference.

Comment: Additional header lines provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header  these may or may not be helpful, just worth a read/try.

Comment: If you cannot resolve your issue, I highly, highly recommend using PHPMailer.

Comment: @DrNawaf the second email is working fine on my side, I just copied and paste your code and change my email address. the email arrived as expected with headings styled

Comment: can you post the contents of email_template.html

Answer (score -2):

Just enable the HTML in php mailer

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

For refrence please see [here the example in github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: He's not using the PHPMailer library.

Comment: i need to contact support now so they can add it.this is shared hosting

Comment: @TFennis I said him to try thius way ok

Comment: For what you are calling suppport?

Comment: there is no php.ini file in cpanel.so should i just create new ? or contact hosting? this is a shared hosting which i am using

Comment: Contact support that is better

Comment: No you don't need to contact any support....  you are not using phpmailer library, u using just php mail, you need to set the html on your email headers

Comment: @PranavMS he's not using phpMailer lib... so this **Just enable the HTML in php mailer** i s not gonna help..