# php mail() function doesn't work on macOs

Tags: php, macos, xampp, brackets

I am learning about using php to send emails. I managed to get brackets working with XAMPP on macOS Mojave and I'm running the following script

```php
<?php
    $emailTo = "me@mydomain.com"; 
    $subject = "I hope this works!";
    $body = "test simple email";
    $headers = "From: me@mydomain.com";

    if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers)){
        echo "Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!";
    } else {
        echo "Your message was not sent successfully.";
    }
?>
```

leads to the following result:

```
Your message was not sent successfully.
```

I am a beginner in doing this and I thought I may ask for some feedback.

Comment: Look for mail [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header)

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to look at the exact error message, see [How can I get the error message for the mail() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3186725)