# Why is PHP mail() giving me error: "Undefined offset: 3" and what is the reason?

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email through the PHP function: `mail()`.
It doesn't work and when I'm trying to see what the error message is, by using the `error_get_last()` => `error_get_last()['message']` function, I only get: `Undefined offset: 3`.

Of what I can see, the `$headers` is the error, since it is the 3rd key in the `mail()` function. I've tried multiple variants of headers. Examples I've tried:

- [Complete mail header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header)

I even tried to copy and only use the very simple example from this post:

- [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Here is the full code I've been using:

```
$toEmail = "Receiver Example < receiver@example.com >";
$subject = "Test email";
$text = "
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Email title</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Thank you for reading this!</h1> 
        <table cellspacing='0' style='width: 100%;'> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Test</td> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
    </body> 
</html>";

$headers = array(
    "From" => "Test Example < test@example.com >",
    "Reply-To" => "Reply < reply@example.com >",
    "X-Sender" => "Reply < reply@example.com >",
    "Return-Path" => "reply@example.com",
    "Content-Type" => "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "MIME-Version" => "1.0",
    "X-Mailer" => "PHP/" . phpversion()
);

$sendEmail = mail($toEmail, $subject, $text, $headers);

if(!$sendEmail){
    return "Error: ".error_get_last()['message'];
}
```

---

Alternative header I've also tried, but with no success:

```
$headers  = "From: Test Example < test@example.com >\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Reply < reply@example.com >\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender: Reply < reply@example.com >\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: reply@example.com\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

---

Do you have an idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: Can you var_dump the entire `error_get_last()` return? I'm not convinced that error is from mail.

Comment: Jonnix - Thank you for your reply! I've should have used the var_dump() before posted the post, because it's showing me that the error is coming from a total different file that I've used the require_once() function. I will keep going on with the investigation :)

Comment: The code as shown does not seem to produce any such error at all. _“Of what I can see, the $headers is the error, since it is the 3rd key in the mail() function.”_ - that appears to be completely the wrong place to look - no one is trying to access any specific array element by any offset there. The error message contains file and line number of where it occurred, so go check what is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jonnix I figured out that the problem is from some very old code I've been using, from a different place in the file directory because of the `require_once()` function.

The solution was simple, use `var_dump()` on the `error_get_last()` function!
It showed me this:

`array(4) {`

`["type"]=> int(8)`

`["message"]=> string(19) "Undefined offset: 3"`

`["file"]=> string(72) "*CORRUPTED FILE LOCATION*"`

`["line"]=> int(59)`

`}`